# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-leaflet'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-leaflet

While trying to run some example code, I get a compilation error;

```
"Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-leaflet' in 'C:\Users...\my-app\src\map'"
```

I'm trying to do this with react and typescipt, and use "react-leaflet"

I've already tried installing both types@react-leaflet and react-leaflet

Here are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "24.0.15",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.4.4",
    "@types/node": "12.0.8",
    "@types/react": "16.8.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.8.4",
    "@types/react-leaflet": "^2.2.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.5.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "typescript": "3.5.2"
  }
```

Comment: I don't see the `react-leaflet` in the dependencies, only the `@types`

Comment: have you tried npm install

Comment: Yeah, i was missing the react-leaflet. I was not awear i needed both, ty Mosh Feu

Comment: Sure :) Good luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't added the react-leaflet dependency, only the types.

Run `npm i react-leaflet` to install the actual package.

Comment: He would probably also want the `--save` flag so that it is added to the package.json

Comment: As of [npm 5](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/161081169345/v500) --save is no longer needed. It now saves it automatically to your package.json

Answer (score 3):

`npm i leaflet`

Run this command also in terminal and it will work